# Showing content, when the page is ready doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've got the script: when the page is ready it shows data from dbase, and that's great working, but after refreshing the page it does show nothing. What's interesting, using Internet Explorer everything is fine. Why?

```js
$(window).ready(function () {
    $("#infinite").append(cos);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) show using `$(document).ready`, not `window`. They mention "Browsers also provide the load event on the window object." but that's a different event I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#infinite").append(cos);
});
```

I guess you're mixing with the:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
  $("#infinite").append(cos);
});
```

which is a different thing.